# how to make check box depends on days of week , knowing that i store as an array?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

i wanna display check box of weekdays - that display the week checked and the other days not checked

```
$days = $user->work_days;
$real_days = explode(',', $days);
$week = array('Saturday','Sunday' ,'Monday','Tuesday' ,'Wendnesday' ,'Thursday' ,'Friday');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($week) ; $i++) {
if (count($real_days) <= $i and  isset($real_days[$i]) and $real_days[$i] ==$i ) {
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='working_days[]' value='$i' checked >" .$week[$i]." <br>"; }else{
 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='working_days[]' value='$i'  >".$week[$i]." <br>";
}
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution, btw you should avoid rewriting the same code twice ;)

```
<?php
$days = 'Monday,Wendnesday';
$real_days = explode(',', $days);
$week = array('Saturday','Sunday' ,'Monday','Tuesday' ,'Wendnesday' ,'Thursday' ,'Friday');
//foreach is more readable
foreach ($week as $dayName) {
    $checked = '';
    //Check if current week day is in real_days
    if (in_array($dayName, $real_days)) {
        $checked = ' checked="checked" ';
    }
    ?>
    <input type='checkbox' name='working_days[]' <?= $checked ?> ><?= $dayName ?><br>
    <?php
}
```